# Conditional Formatting to highlight only certain duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I run a report daily where everyone is either a `type 1` membership or a `type 2` membership. I need Excel automatically to highlight everyone with the same ID but *different* membership types.

If they have the same ID and the same membership type, they should remain unhighlighted.[It should look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Iyk.jpg)

[image: It should look like this.]

I've been told VBA is a hard no.

Can this be done via Conditional Formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems to work for your example. Please select ColumnsA:C and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)<>COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting (yellow fill?) OK, OK.